# 404 error from my node server

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic3

so I am making an Ionic app and I have a node server that is connected to a mongoose database, however, my Node server keeps returning a 404 error. The following is from my Node terminal:

```
GET / 404 2.975 ms - 139
GET /favicon.ico 404 0.427 ms - 150
GET /api/courses 404 1.415 ms - 150
GET /api/courses 404 0.196 ms - 150
OPTIONS /api/courses 204 3.840 ms - 0
POST /api/courses 404 40.388 ms - 151
GET /api/courses 404 0.247 ms - 150
GET /api/courses 404 0.201 ms - 150
GET /api/courses 404 0.271 ms - 150
GET /api/courses 404 0.188 ms - 150
GET /api/courses 404 0.184 ms - 150
GET /api/courses 404 0.154 ms - 150
GET / 404 0.190 ms - 139
GET / 404 0.198 ms - 139
GET /api/courses 404 2.366 ms - 150
GET /api/courses 404 0.195 ms - 150
GET /api/courses 404 0.195 ms - 150
GET /api/courses 404 0.410 ms - 150
GET /api/courses 404 0.204 ms - 150
OPTIONS /api/courses 204 0.727 ms - 0
POST /api/courses 404 3.987 ms - 151
GET / 404 0.168 ms - 139
GET /api/courses 404 0.209 ms - 150
```

[And this is a screenshot from the console in the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSrI0.png)

I am not sure why this is happening, this is my server file: server.js:

```
var express =  require('express');
var app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var cors = require('cors');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/courses');

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({'extended': 'true'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/vnd.api+json' }));
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, PUT');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
 });

 var Course = mongoose.model('Course', {
    coursecode: String,
    email: String,
    name: String
 })

 //Routes

 app.get('api/courses', function(req, res){
     console.log("Fetching Courses")

     Course.find(function(err, courses){
         if (err)
            res.send(err)

         res.json(courses);
     });
 });

 app.post('api/courses', function(req, res){
     console.log("Creating Entry in course");

     Course.create({
         title: req.body.title,
         email: req.body.email,
         name: req.body.name,
         done: false

     }, function(err, courses){
         if (err)
            res.send(err);

         Course.find(function(err, courses){
             if (err)
                res.send(err)

             res.json(courses);
         });
     });
});

app.delete('api/courses/:course_id', function(req, res){
    Course.remove({
        _id: req.params.course_id}, function(err, course){
        });
    });

app.listen(8080);
console.log("Listening on port 8080")
```

When I run node server.js, I see in the terminal "Listening on port 8080", so I know everything is running okay. However, when I go on http://localhost:8080, I get an error CANNOT GET/.

Appreciate all help!

Comment: You haven't defined a root route... did you try going to `/api/courses` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `app.get('api/courses',` to `app.get('/api/courses',`.

You need to add a slash(/) in app route.

Refer here for more about routes: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a root (`/`) route. It doesn't give that to you for free. Try creating one:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
     console.log("Root Route")
     res.json({ message: "hello world" });
});
```